# É possível usar o K-means (ou outro método de clusterização) com limite de pontos?

Tags: python, ciência-de-dados, k-means

Estou desenvolvendo um código de cluster com k-means e tenho a seguinte pergunta: É possível determinar os limites de pontos por cluster com k-means ou outro algoritmo?

Explicando melhor o caso, no código abaixo, tenho duas centróides pré-determinadas e 12 pontos. Depois de executar o k-means, temos 8 pontos na centróide 0 e 4 pontos na centróide 1.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np

#Centroids:
refs = [[-22.87042313, -43.33995681], [-22.91265768, -43.23596109]]
kmeans_model = KMeans(n_clusters=len(refs), random_state=0).fit(refs)
ref_labels = kmeans_model.labels_
centroids = kmeans_model.cluster_centers_

#Points:
points = [[-22.8595871, -43.2385504], [-23.0144844, -43.4727984], [-22.8727929, -43.4082954],
          [-22.9478637, -43.3652225], [-22.8213579, -43.1740529], [-22.9592171, -43.3508173],
          [-22.8236928, -43.3203929], [-22.9027656, -43.3541462], [-22.8749724, -43.5034297],
          [-22.8456399, -43.2840653], [-22.8893855, -43.2424886], [-22.8499984, -43.2564374]]

#Clustering:
kmeans_model.predict(points)
Output: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int32)
```

Eu posso determinar quantos pontos ficará em cada cluster e ter uma especíe de 'sobra'?

Por exemplo:

centroid 0 = 4 pontos

centroid 1 = 3 pontos

rodar o k-means...

saída: [1,0,0,0,1,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA]
Os valores NA seriam a "sobra", valores que não são próximos o suficiente para conseguir uma "vaga" no cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você deva mudar sua abordagem. Se o objetivo é ter "valores que não são próximos o suficiente para conseguir uma 'vaga' no cluster", uma abordagem de clusterização por densidade parece mais adequado.

Sugiro tentar o [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html) (ou até o [OPTICS](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.OPTICS.html#sklearn.cluster.OPTICS)), que está implementado no sklearn, então basta importar e utilizar o algoritmo:

```
clustering = DBSCAN(eps=3, min_samples=2).fit(X)
```

Tente otimizar o parâmetro epsilon (`eps`), que representa a distância máxima entre dois pontos para que um seja considerado na vizinhança do outro.